# kube-prometheus rule KubeControllerManagerDown is firing

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

Manually installed kube-prometheus using https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/tree/main/manifests without using jb.

Rule is firing:

```
name: KubeControllerManagerDown
expr: absent(up{job="kube-controller-manager"} == 1)
```

even if I create these services:
https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/1859#issuecomment-437740104

How to debug this issue?

Comment: `KubeControllerManagerDown` and `KubeSchedulerDown` are both firing but they should not. Looks like a bug to me (k8s v1.20, kops).

Answer (score 7):

Are you running on a managed Kubernetes service, such as AWS EKS?
These services may be hidden from you, if so.